# How to check Bloom Filter used in one old partition

Tags: hive, bloom-filter

I have a table with some partitions and recently the bloom filter was changed.
is there a way to see which bloom filter was used in the old data?

As long i know once you change the bloom filter, only new data will be affected.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I found a way.

executing the orc dump command, its possible to identify:

hive --orcfiledump data/details/TABLENAME/event_date=2019081200/000001_0 | grep BLOOM_FILTER